# Boolean topoi and classical logic

Tags: logic, model-theory, topos-theory

Let $T$ be a theory in classical (finitary) first-order logic over some language $L$. Then $T$ is equivalent over classical logic to its *Morleyization* $T^m$, i.e. the theory in the language $L^m$ which has a relation symbol for each formula of $L$ and the obvious axioms. That is, the natural interpretation of $L$ in $L^m$ induces a bijection of $Set$-models, which is even an equivalence of categories if we use elementary embeddings for morphisms.

This leads to the following conundrum:

1. By D1.5.13 in the Elephant, the theory $T^m$ admits an axiomatization in coherent logic.
2. The category $\operatorname{Def}_{T^m}$ of $T^m$-definable sets is clearly Boolean (i.e. subobjects have complements), so the classifying topos $\mathcal E_{T^m}$ is also Boolean.
3. But Blass and Scedrov showed in [Boolean Classifying Topoi](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(83)90069-5) that the classifying topos $\mathcal E_{S}$ of a coherent theory $S$ is Boolean only under much more restrictive conditions (stronger than being $\aleph_0$-categorical!).

But

4. There exist classical first-order theories which are not $\aleph_0$-categorical.

This is a contradiction. So I'm not understanding something.

**Question 1:** Where am I going wrong here?

**Question 2:** I suppose the most likely answer is that just because a coherent category is Boolean, perhaps that doesn't imply that its classifying topos is Boolean? If that's the case, what would be a simple counterexample where one can see this in action?

**Question 3:** If classifying topoi of classical theories which eliminate quantifiers are not necessarily (or even typically!) Boolean, then is there some other way to characterize them among topoi? Or at least some interesting necessary condition they satisfy, such as being DeMorgan?

Comment: What is $\mathsf{Def}_{T^m}$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber $Def_{T^m}$ is the category of definable sets. So an object is a formula $\varphi(\bar x)$ in $L^m$ up to $T^m$-provable equivalence; a morphism from $\varphi(\bar x)$ to $\psi(\bar y)$ is a formula $\chi(\bar x, \bar y)$ which is $T^m$-provably a function from the set defined by $\varphi$ to that defined by $\psi$, again up to $T^m$-provable equivalence. The classifying topos $\mathcal E_{T^m}$ is sheaves on $Def_{T^m}$ in the canonical Grothendieck topology -- roughly the Ind-definable sets. Just noticed that I failed to complete this sentence in the question --  fixed, thanks!

Comment: I don't see why $\mathsf{Def}_S$ being Boolean should imply that $\mathcal{E}_S$ is Boolean for $S$ a coherent theory.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks! I was starting to circle around that conclusion too, so I guess that answers Question 1. Somehow it's surprising to me to realize that that the classifying topoi of classical theories are not "Boolean"! I'm reading a bit more and learning that sheaves on a topological space are De Morgan iff the space is extremally disconnected (i.e. a much stronger condition than totally disconnected!) so it seems my guess that these topoi would be De Morgan is also wrong. I'm very curious now how to characterize "classical" topoi if their internal logic is pretty far from classical!

Comment: I agree that Booleanness of Def doesn't imply Booleanness of the classifying topos. Intuitively, truth values in the classifying topos come from sieves in Def, which amount to possibly-infinite disjunctions of first-order formulas. The first-order formulas have nice, Boolean complements, but the infinite disjunctions might not. The relevance of $\aleph_0$-categoricity is that, thanks to Ryll-Nardzewski's theorem, it prevents genuinely infinite disjunctions.

Comment: A good example might be the theory of the integers with the successor function, i.e., just one function symbol $S$ and axioms saying it's a bijection with no cycles of any finite length. The definable set of all pairs $(x,y)$ has a sieve generated by the subsets $\{(x,y):(x\neq S^ny)\land(y\neq S^nx)\}$ for all $n$. That sieve has no complement.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I think that should be an answer.